# cURL not working while fetching Google API data

Tags: php, json, api, google-maps, curl

So, I'm trying to fetch API-data using [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), but I get the message "fail" from the else-statement in the code below.
The API call is [Google geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding) for fetching coordinates.

**The code:**

```
 <?php 
    require_once('../db.php');
    $api_key = "somekey";
    $sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT `County` FROM `table`"); 
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    
    /* Fetch county */ 
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery))  { 
        $countyArr = $rows['County']; 
    
        /* Call google API and save coordinates for each county */ 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$countyArr.",+CA&key=".$api_key."");
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $json= curl_exec($ch, true);
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        
        if ($obj->status == "OK") {
            $lat = $obj->results->location->lat;
            $lng = $obj->results->location->lng;
            echo $lat;
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

- I intended to use `get_file_contents()` earlier but it seems like my hosting has deactivated that function.
- Adding `allow_url_fopen = on` to php.ini didn't do the trick.
- It seems like my [hosting allows cURL](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-curl-2901), so that shouldn't be the problem.
- I've tried to manually go to the API-call and I get a webpage showing the correct JSON-data.
- The SQL-query seems to be working fine too.

**Edit:**

- I tried echoing `$obj->status` and `$obj->results->location->lat` in
  the else-statement, nothing showed up. So `$obj` seems to be NULL

Comment: I see two potential problems in your example: `curl_exec` may return `false` if the request fails, `json_decode` may return `null` if the decode fails (because it received `false` from `curl_exec`). In addition to catching these error cases, it would be valuable to fire "tracer bullets" -- `var_dump` statements -- to confirm that those return values are what you would expect.

Comment: To save yourself the time of writing and debugging an HTTP client by using Guzzle: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems it fails while verifying certificate, you could disable CA verification

To  turn off certificate verification (for both peer and host verification) set the following options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

**Example**

How to disable certificate verification

```
$address = "Ontario,CA";
$apiKey = "";

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $address; //. "&key=" . $apiKey;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  // Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
print json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```