# Getting the Altitude / Elevation from Google Maps address with the Elevation API

Tags: json, google-maps, google-elevation-api

Im trying the echo the elevation of an address in PHP.
I am using the Google Elevation API - [LINK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro)

I already have the latitude and longitude.
The following link:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=40.7143528,-74.0059731&key=myapikey`

will produce these results in json:

`{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 9.774918556213379,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 40.7143528,
            "lng" : -74.00597310000001
         },
         "resolution" : 19.08790397644043
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}`

How can I echo the elevation?
something like `<?php echo 'elevation'; ?>`

Thank you

Comment: Hey, you shared your private API_KEY. I suggest you remove it from the question and regenerate a new for you from API Console

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by changing the response to be xml format to make things easier:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/xml?locations=40.7143528,-74.0059731&key=yourKey
>   From there if your php code supports it you can do this:

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/xml?locations=40.7143528,-74.0059731&key=myapikey');
$results = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
echo $results->elevation;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I get 2 errors.  The one I may hace fixed with `function file_get_contents_curl( $url ) {

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );

  $data = curl_exec( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  return $data;

}` and changing to `file_get_contents_curl` [link]https://gist.github.com/schalkjoubert/0d9be4969990e37dda6594347e8ce983

Comment: The problem appears to be that you cannot connect due to a certificate verification error. [This is not needed and you can disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858367/curl-not-working-while-fetching-google-api-data).

Comment: Thank you, tried that, and got a bit further. I do admit, I do admit, I'm treading in an area way above my level.

`$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=40.7143528,-74.0059731&key=AIzaSyCM1fCTYKPhk6tDCqsVNhcXto6aqjUc0yY";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  // Disable SSL verification

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

This prints everything, including elevation.

Comment: This is what i see on my screen:

`"{\n \"results\" : [\n {\n \"elevation\" : 9.774918556213379,\n \"location\" : {\n \"lat\" : 40.7143528,\n \"lng\" : -74.00597310000001\n },\n \"resolution\" : 19.08790397644043\n }\n ],\n \"status\" : \"OK\"\n}\n"`

Comment: That's because you have `print json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` at the end of your code. Just remove that line and it'll stop print out to screen.

Comment: Keep your chin up, if you search Stack Overflow for each error that you get. I'm sure you'll get it in the end. I can see that my answers have been useful, I'd be very grateful for recognition through an upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164694/discussion-between-franco-vizcarra-and-user1664798).

Answer (score 1):

The thread is old but I found an alternative that can be used to do an elevation query without google and without a key.
The link:
https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/eudem25m?locations=51.875127,10.65432
gives the following result:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "dataset": "eudem25m", 
      "elevation": 352.5389709472656, 
      "location": {
        "lat": 51.875127, 
        "lng": 10.65432
      }
    }
  ], 
  "status": "OK"
}
```

which can be evaluated with php:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
$result = $json['results'][0]['elevation'];
```

Note: when querying in a loop, a sleep must be included, e.g. sleep(2);